# Android App not appearing in the first page of google play even with "exact name" search

Tags: android, search, google-play

I published the below android app in the market 2 days ago. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatappnext.topmusicvideos.
Even if i search by the exact app name the app is not appearing in the first page of Google play page. However when i search for other apps they appear as the first result in the Google play page when i search using the exact app name. Am i missing something. Kindly help me figure out if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: @Dalmas yesterday when I checked it was only in the 2nd page. Even today it is not the first result. Apps whose name don't match my app's title 'Top Music Videos' ex: Vevo, Airsync etc. appear higher in the list. I was under the impression that if i search by title name the app would be the first result.

Comment: Hey, I have same problem. I uploaded my app before 15 days. But still i can't find my app by searching it with exact name(Fun With Math Game) on play store. By searching my other app and from them the link more from this developer i can find my this app. My app is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zil.FWMG#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDIxMiwiY29tLnppbC5GV01HIl0. Any solution for that?

Comment: Looks like you did ok in the end. Over 1m downloads. My app was firs tin the results, now it can't be found anywhere whatsoever. I am a little miffed how, in one day it can not be found at all. Still onwards and upwards

Answer (score 2):

Well, I just understood that you are asking for the bad ranking of your app in the search results.

The ranking algorithm doesn't order the results only by app names, it also includes app ratings, number of downloads, and probably some other stuff. The app name and description are used to filter the results and remove irrelevant ones, but I'm not even sure if they are used to order the results.

In fact, it is probably a bad idea to use three very common keywords as your app title. Google tries very hard to downrank this kind of titles, because they try to order the apps by quality rather than keywords.

It would be too easy to make a poor app and appear first in the search results just because the other ones don't use the right keywords. I don't say that your app is bad, but google algorithm might think so.

Answer (score 1):

It may take some time for your app to get indexed in the search results. The site updates their listings in a few days. Wait for sometime and it will appear.

Answer (score 1):

I found it by application package name and even by application's name :)